# Full Website Address not Passing through PHP Post Form Properly

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have created a form using HTML / AJAX / PHP. The form requires that a website be inputted into one of the fields, here is an example:

```
http://www.teamexpress.com/catalog/thumbnail.jsp?N=46&36&Ns=PRODUCT_AFFINITY%7C1&Nty=1&Ntk=Def&Ntx=mode%20matchallpartial&Ntt=sale15&sc=TBX
```

The input field id="sample_page" and it is transferring over to my AJAX/ Php script fine, the only problem is that the $_POST data is splitting up the website address:

```
$_POST["sample_page"] is returning this: http://www.teamexpress.com/catalog/thumbnail.jsp?N=46
```

instead of the full address as noted above. It looks like the $_POST data is splitting the site up by "&" or "=". I'm sure there is a simple workaround for this that I am missing, as I am new to all of this.

Thank you for your help.

Edit: Here is the scripts I am using:

post_vars is printing out on console.log like this:

```
store_name=a&sample_page=http://www.teamexpress.com/catalog/thumbnail.jsp?N=46&36&Ns=PRODUCT_AFFINIT…&product_misc_info_2=//&product_misc_info_3=//&product_container_search=0&
```

This is my AJAX request:

```
    var new_site_array = ["store_name", "sample_page", "product_container", "product_title", "product_link", "product_image", "product_price", "product_original_price", "product_discount", "product_misc_info_1", "product_misc_info_2", "product_misc_info_3"];
var post_data_array = [];

function fix_container_search_syntax(search_value, container_search_checked)
{

if(container_search_checked == 1)
{
    search_value = "./" + search_value;
}
else
{
    search_value = "//" + search_value;
}
return search_value;
}

function new_site_validate_test(new_site_array)
{
//Check form for any problems
var new_site_fields_filled_in = 12;
var alert_text = "";
var show_alert = 0;

//Check if Container Search is checked
var container_search_checked = 0;
if(document.getElementById("product_container_search").checked)
{
    container_search_checked = 1;
}

//
//Check if more than one field is entered and sample page has http:// format
//
for (i=0; i< new_site_array.length; i++)
{
    var check_new_site_form = document.getElementById(new_site_array[i]).value;
    if(new_site_array[i] == "sample_page" && check_new_site_form.indexOf("http://") < 0)
    {
        show_alert = 1;
        alert_text += "Sample Page is not formatted correctly\n\n";
    }
    if(check_new_site_form.length < 1 )
    {
        new_site_fields_filled_in--;
    }
    if(i>2)
    {
        var syntax_fix_form_field = fix_container_search_syntax(check_new_site_form, container_search_checked);
        post_data_array.push(new_site_array[i] + ';' + syntax_fix_form_field );
    }
    else if(i==2)
    {
        post_data_array.push(new_site_array[i]  + ';//' + check_new_site_form);
    }
    else
    {
        post_data_array.push(new_site_array[i] + ';' + check_new_site_form);
    }
}

//
//Add field to see if product container search is checked
//
post_data_array.push("product_container_search;" + container_search_checked);

//Alert Section
if(new_site_fields_filled_in < 2)
{
    show_alert = 1;
    alert_text += "More Than 1 Field Including the Sample Page Field must be filled in.\n";
}

//
//If Any Alerts show alert windows and stop function else continue to test
//
if(show_alert>0)
{
    alert(alert_text);
}

//
//Run Test Scrape with fields
//
else
{
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "./php/new_site_test.php";
    var post_vars = "";
    var array_split;
    for(i= 0; i<post_data_array.length; i++)
    {
        array_split = post_data_array[i].split(";")
        post_vars = post_vars + array_split[0] + "=" + array_split[1] + "&"
    }
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        console.log(hr);
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200)
        {
            console.log(post_vars);
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("results_inner").innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("results").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("results_inner").innerHTML = return_data;
            console.log(return_data);
        }
    }
    hr.send(post_vars);
}
```

}

I hope this code isn't too messy. This is my first attempt at doing any of this, as I am self taught. I tried initially putting the values through a JSON file, but couldn't quite seem to figure it out.

Php is simple right now just to validate:

```
echo($_POST["sample_page"] . "</br>");
```

Comment: "I'm sure there is a simple workaround for this that I am missing" — There is. Properly encode your form fields. How do you do that depends on the method you are using to construct them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> post_vars = post_vars + array_split[0] + "=" + array_split[1] + "&"
> ```

You need to encode each key and value for the form data string with `encodeURIComponent`

```
post_vars = post_vars + 
    encodeURIComponent(array_split[0]) + 
    "=" + 
    encodeURIComponent(array_split[1]) + 
    "&";
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I knew there was some simple solution I was missing.